# Unable to read path using os.listdir

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner and newly join this forum. I have tried many times to read a list of image dataset into my code using os.listdir.

I use code:

```
img_path = "images/train"
for image in os.listdir(img_path):
    print(image)
```

Unfortunately, error occured:
**FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'images/testing'**

Does it have any issue with Windows? I have tried to add path in the Environment Variable but the same error occurred. Please anyone expert can advise me on how to overcome this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the complete path (Absolute path) of your images folder.

Example: `C:/Users/User/images/train`

Answer (score 0):

Give the absolute path:

```
import os
img_path = os.path.abspath("train")
for image in os.listdir(img_path):
    print(image)
```

Comment: thank you for ur kind comment. it helps me solved it